# Displaying selected observations performed next day in SAS

Tags: date, sas, dataset, selection

If I have a dataset that looks like this for variables ID, DATE, Procedure:

```
'12 01jan2013 a'

'12 01feb2013 b'

'13 14feb2013 c'

'13 15feb2013 a'

'24 01mar2013 c'

'24 02mar2013 a'

'26 01oct2013 a'

'26 02oct2013 a'
```

I would like to output only those observations where Procedure ='a' and that was performed NEXT DAY after Procedure ="c" for each ID (by ID). So from the example above I would end up with:

```
'13 15feb2013 a'

'24 02mar2013 a'
```

Could you help me with a SAS code for this operation?

Comment: Hello, What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am using 'retain' and New_date=DATE + 1 and 'if then do' statements by ID. But I can't figure out how to have the Procedure variable to be specific.

Comment: Does the outputted obs have to have the same IDs as the yesterday's Procedure=`c`? I have used the retain statement that you've mentioned and also using SAS date values instead of the date formats in the example data set in my code below.

Comment: Yes, the IDs have to be the same. I am trying to see if IDs had Procedure =a done on the next day after Prodedure=c was done on this ID.

Comment: I've altered my code a bit by retaining id as well after you have clarified more about your required conditions. Cheers.

Comment: I have a question. My example is presorted. I'd like to ask if I have unsorted data should sort it by ID and DATE before running this type of data step or sorting by ID only is enough?

Comment: To be safe I think you should sort it by both. This is because you'll want to have the dates which are one day after Procedure=`c`. If it's not sorted by dates as well, SAS won't be able to detect them if they are 1 day after procedure=`c` because the dat step is structured like a loop. (i.e. it can't go backwards)

Comment: But ultimately, test your data first by substituting different data combinations into the sample to see if my code still holds under different situations. For example, I think my code still works if there are two consecutive occurrences of the same procedure=`a` that are one day after procedure=`c` and have same ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, you're on the right track. `Retain` is one way to do it. You can then convert the dates into SAS date values (i.e. number of days after Jan 1 1960) for your conditional statement.

```
data test(drop=retaindate rid);
    infile datalines truncover;
    input ID date date9. Procedure $;

    if Procedure = 'c' then do;
        retaindate = date;
        rid = id;
        retain retaindate rid;
    end;
    if Procedure='a' and rid=id and date=retaindate+1 then do;
        output;
    end;
    format date date9.;
    datalines;
    12 01jan2013 a

    12 01feb2013 b

    13 14feb2013 c

    13 15feb2013 a

    24 01mar2013 c

    24 02mar2013 a

    26 01oct2013 a

    26 02oct2013 a
    ;
    run;
```

Comment: This will overflow between different IDs as it stands - just needs a bit of first.ID logic to deal with that.

Comment: Yeah you're right about that, I didn't catch that in the log. I tweaked it a bit. thanks for informing me.